# List.split() not cross platform?

Tags: python

Recently I had some trouble writing code in Ubuntu and make it work in Windows.

Code on both platforms:

[image]

Output Ubuntu (that's what I want):

[image]

Output Windows:

[image]

As you can see, split on windows adds a `'/'` instead of splitting the list by `'/'`. Is the `list.split()` not cross platform?

Comment: `/` and `\\` are two different characters

Comment: Is there a simpler way to solve this other than checking for the OS in an if-statement?

Comment: What makes you think `list.split()` s the problem? What should it do in your opinion if there are no `/`s ion the string, but only `\`s?

Comment: please [Do not post image of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/479251)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `os.sep`

**Ex:**

```
import os

importpath = __file__
print(importpath.split(os.sep))
```

Comment: Kind of right, but that doesn't include the case where a path under windows is separated by a `/`, which is valid too.

Comment: This works in my case. Thank you. Could you elaborate how `os.sep` works exactly? How does it recognize by which characters it has to seperate?

Comment: Have a look at the documentation of [`os.sep`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.sep).

Comment: Note that it also reads "Note that knowing this is not sufficient to be able to parse or concatenate pathnames — use `os.path.split()` and `os.path.join()` — but it is occasionally useful."

Answer (score 2):

A more "universal" way to do it is by using `os.path.split()`. This splits the path at the last separator. The first part must be treated iteratively or recursively.

Under Windows, think of splitting the drive letter as well.

Something like

```
drv, path = os.path.splitdrive(fullpath)
spl = []
while path:
    path, lastpart = os.path.split(path)
    spl.append(lastpart)
spl.append(drv) # as needed
spl.reverse()
```

should do it, but I don't have Windows at hand and cannot test it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be super safe, you should use repeatedly `os.path.split`, or test for both `os.sep` and `os.altsep` as separator.

`__file__` will always use `os.sep`, but when you get a path from other code or by direct input from a user, chances are that `os.altsep` (`'/'` on Windows) is used.

Example on Windows:

```
>>> path = os.path.join('c:\\a', 'c/d')
>>> print(path)
'c:\\a\\c/d'
>>> pathsep = re.compile(r'\\|/')
>>> pathsep.split(path)
['c:', 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

Alternatively:

```
 def safe_split(path):
    res = []
    while True:
        path, tail = os.path.split(path)
        if len(tail) == 0:
            break
        res.append(tail)
    res.append(path)           # do not forget the initial segment
    res.reverse()
    return res
```

and

```
>>> safe_split('c:\\a\\c/d')
['c:\\', 'a', 'c', 'd']
```